# Validation of live search Vuew

Tags: validation, search, input, vue.js, render

Hej,
I have a problem to validate live search in Vue. I've dome many attempts but it the end I cannot run that..
Can some would advice me how I could start writing this validation?
Example: 
If I type in search something that doesnt exist make alert

```
      <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search..." class="search" />

export default {
  data(){
    return {
    users: [],
    search: ''
  }
},
  mounted(){
    fetch("https://api.github.com/users?since=135")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.users = data;
    // console.log(data);
    })
  },
  computed:{
    filteredUsers: function(users){
      return this.users.filter((users) => {
        return users.login.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
  });
   }
  },
}
```

I have doubts about If else statement between which render I should put that..

Comment: Do you have any console error?

Comment: no, I dont  have. Live search is working perfectly. I stacked in validation ..

Comment: Where is the html code for `this.users` ?

Comment: You can add if else condition in vue html